# fndraw on datatables not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the datatables plugin and want to reload the sorting of the table columns by the click of a button. I'm changing the content of the table clientside. But nothing happens when I click redrawBtn. Everything else is working properly.

```
// datatable config
var oTable = tablesorterEl.dataTable({
"bPaginate": false,
"bLengthChange": false,
"bFilter": true,
"bSort": true,
"bInfo": false,
"bAutoWidth": false,
"bRetrieve": false,
"asSorting": true,
"bServerSide": false,
"bSearchable": true,
"aaSorting": [],                    
"oLanguage": {
"sSearch": ""
},
"bStateSave": true
});

// redraw button
$('.redrawBtn').click(function(){

  oTable.fnDraw();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want fnDraw to re-sort dataTable you should write oTable.fnDraw(true).

pietro

Answer (score 1):

I found out I have to manipulate the dom using a dataTables function. Like

```
$('.redrawBtn').click(function(){
   oTable.fnUpdate( 'Example update', 0, 0 ); // Single cell. Will redraw by default
});
```

Comment: You could accept your own answer, so people can see the question is "closed" and also benefit from your solution.